# 403 forbidden error on Ajax post request [codeigniter captcha]

Tags: php, ajax, captcha, codeigniter-3

I have an issue with codeigniter when I add a captcha to my form. I refresh page the captcha work but if I click on refresh icon it not work then show me error on the below image :

[image]

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.refresh').click(function(){
        var res;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://anana.dev/register/refresh_captcha',
            success: function(res){
                if(res){
                    $('.image').html(res);
                }
            }
        })
    });
});
```

+here this my form:

```
<form action="/register" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="<?=$csrf['name'];?>" value="<?=$csrf['hash'];?>" />
    <?php echo $captcha; ?>
    <a class="refresh" href="javascript:;">
        <img src="images/refresh.png">
    </a>
    <input type="text" name="captcha">
<button type="submit" class="button userlogin">Apply</button>
```

Comment: Show what you've tried so far...

Comment: can you please show some part of your code ?

Comment: are you checking the csrf in your http://anana.dev/register/refresh_captcha page ?

Comment: Change permissions  of  http://anana.dev/register/refresh_captcha

Comment: Url not found so this error will be occur.